# Data grid view and collections as data source / Issue

Tags: gridview, datasource

I have a simple collection

```
string[] IDs =  {"1", "2" , "3", "4"};

Collection<TempOBJ> collection1 = reader.Read()<TempOBJ>(IDs);
```

After the previous lines, collection1 contains 4 rows with several columns:

```
session  |   FirstName  | LastName  |  serial  |  Address |  randomID  |

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

1            Sam               John      d3s3     sample      123

2            Sam               John      d3s3     sample      345

3            Sam               John      6g55     asdfggh     678

4            Joe               Sammy      d7g5     asdfgh      987
```

And then I set the data source of  a grid view to the collection:

```
GridView1.DataSource = collection1 ;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

When the code runs it displays all of the columns. What I want is specific columns like FirstName, LastName, and Address only.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is reader?

Comment: This is just a method I use, it is custom. It fills the collection with data and I want specific fields in the grid view to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. I set the AutoGenerateColumns of the gridview to false and set the columns manually in the markup code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Address"  HeaderText="Address"/>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind is the same.